Unable to access com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavaProcessingEnvironment
I am working on a data structure framework, a personal project of mine for learning purposes.
I have the following setup
I am running IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2 Ultimate with OpenJDK17 and Maven as a build system
I have a bunch of annotations that are used to mark parts of the library
@Implementation determines the type of implementation of class whether an ABSTRACTION or IMPLEMENTATION.
@EngineNature defines the behavior of the engine, ordering type and nature
For example
//An ABSTRACTION
@Implementation(ImplementationType.ABSTRACTION)
public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractDataEngine<E> {
...
}

//An MUTABLE Implementation
@Implementation(ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION)
@EngineNature(nature = Nature.MUTABLE, behaviour = EngineBehaviour.DYNAMIC, order = Ordering.UNSORTED)
public class DynamicArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
...
}

//An IMMUTABLE Implementation
@Implementation(ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION)
@EngineNature(nature = Nature.IMMUTABLE, behaviour = EngineBehaviour.FIXED_LENGTH, order = Ordering.UNSUPPORTED)
public class ImmutableList<E> extends FixedArrayList<E>{
...
}

I also have another annotation @Behavior for methods which defines if it is MUTABLE , IMMUTABLE or UNSUPPORTED
I have two modules in my project DataEngineFramework
DataEngineCore and DataEngine. The core module contains important top level classes and the annotation processors for the main module. The main module contains concrete and abstract implementations of various data-structures.
I already have setup various annotation processors that check various conditions,
IMPLEMENTATION conditions
if(element.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT))
    injectError("An implementation cannot be declared abstract. " +
          ((TypeElement)element).getQualifiedName()+ " is declared abstract", element);
else if(!hasEnclosedIterator((TypeElement) element))
    injectError("An implementation must contain an iterator implementation. " +
          ((TypeElement)element).getQualifiedName() +" has no concrete iterator.", element);
else if(isNotSubClassOf((TypeElement) element))
     injectError("An implementation must be a direct or indirect subclass of " +
           "AbstractDataEngine. " + ((TypeElement)element).getQualifiedName() + " does not have " +
                                    "AbstractDataEngine as a superclass ",element );


ABSTRACTION conditions
if(!element.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT))
   injectError("An abstraction must be declared abstract "
        + ((TypeElement)element).getQualifiedName() + " is not declared abstract", element);
else if(isNotSubClassOf((TypeElement) element))
   injectError("An abstraction must be a direct or indirect subclass of " +
        "AbstractDataEngine "+ ((TypeElement)element).getQualifiedName() + " does not have " +
                    "AbstractDataEngine as a superclass ",element );

The most important feature is the compile time code generation via modifying the AST of a class.
Basically what I do is, I traverse the hierarchy and find all the methods that have been marked as MUTABLE and store them in an LinkedHashSet My problem is that I wanna inject them into the AST or something similar to inject the additional code. My idea is that I can leave methods that are MUTABLE with respect to an IMMUTABLE Implementation and let my processor search and find all the methods that need to have an override. The override is simply throwing an exception.
Example of methods being marked
  @Override
    @Behaviour(Type.MUTABLE)
    public void add(E item) {
      ...
}

  @Override
    @Behaviour(Type.IMMUTABLE)
    public int getLastIndexOf(E item) {
        ....
}

How do I achieve this behavior?

This is obviously overkill for such a simple project but yeah, I am doing it for educational purposes

You should provide complete errors

It’s much simpler to provide throwing default methods in the interface or even better, not include modification methods in the base interface in the first place. Besides that, annotation processors are not supposed to modify the AST. Every processor doing so, is a hack and problems accessing the compiler’s internal classes are expected.

Yeah, that is true, but like I said, I am just doing it to explore what can be done with Java, trying to get into every nook and cranny

You can do that, but when you run into problems, you should not assume that everyone knows how you accessed what is not supposed to be accessed. As aled said, you should provide complete errors, together with the code that causes the error. It’s good to provide context, but the majority of what you posted is irrelevant to the actual problem.
